# GoLang issue: How to pass key.pem, cert.pem, chain.pem certificates in GoLang

Tags: go, https, client-certificates

I am trying with the following code by passing cert.pem, key.pem and ..chain.pem but getting status:500 as the service is not able to read these certificates for https RESTful webservice. I went through all the examples in net and tried but still getting same exception.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "io"        
)

func main() {

    UserName := "user"
    appName := "AP"
    PasswordKey := "key"
    ServerName := "server"
    Sid := "sid" 

    // Load client cert
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("/cert.pem", "/key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Load CA cert
    caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/xyz.chain.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    ok := caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)
    if !ok {
        panic("failed to parse root certificate")
    }

    fmt.Println("CERT: ",cert)

    // Setup HTTPS client
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
        ServerName: "serverName",
        RootCAs:      caCertPool,
    }

    tlsConfig.BuildNameToCertificate()
    transport := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig}
    client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
    fmt.Println("CLIENT: ",client)

 r := strings.NewReader("{\"userName\" : \"" +UserName+"\",\"appName\" : \""+appName+"\",\"passwordKey\" : \""+PasswordKey+"\",\"serverName\" : \""+ServerName+"\",\"sid\" : \""+Sid+"\"}")
        lr := io.Reader(r)


    resp, err := client.Post("https://xzytr/password/txt","application/json",lr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(contents))
}
```

Comment: Are the files really in `/`? What's the error from your program?

Comment: Yes. Those are paths for the file. I am getting status:500 Null Pointer Exception, as the service is not able to read these certificates for https RESTful webservice.

Comment: That's not a Go error. Please show us the exact error from the code above. Your code will try to deterrence a nil pointer if there's an error with client.Post, but that's separate from loading the certs.

Comment: From the server Side we are trying to read the certificates in the Request,and that time it is throwing this Exception. `CLIENT:  &{0xc8e6090 <nil> <nil> 0}{"timestamp":1460546631323,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.NullPointerException","message":"No message available","path":"../.."`